# How to remove child dom elements classes in JS or Jquery in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below DOM structure and js code.

```
//html
<div class="my-app">
    <a class="anc">Link1</a>
    <a class="anc">Link2</a>
    <a class="anc">Link3</a>
    <a class="anc">Link4</a>
</div>

//js
var parentElm = $('div').find('.my-app') //get the parent node
var childElms = parentElm.find('a'); //select all 'a'inside parents
var total = childElms.length;

for(var i=0;i<total;i++)
{
childElms.last().removeClass('anc');
}
```

Issue I am facing is, above code removes class from only one 'a'element(i.e Link4) though loop runs 4 times. So what I am missing here? I have searched around bit did not get any reference.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: check this URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write in a one line code with-out using loop using jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var parentElm = $('div.my-app a:last').removeClass('anc');
});
```

```css
.anc{
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-app">
    <a class="anc">Link1</a>
    <a class="anc">Link2</a>
    <a class="anc">Link3</a>
    <a class="anc">Link4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to remove classes for all child elements from last to first ones actually.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using jQuery in your project, you could take advantage of its `children` and `each` methods, as shown below.

The `children` method will search for every element inside the specified parent, while `each` will loop through them.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 'use strict';
 $('button').on('click', () => {
  $(".my-app").children('.anc').each((i, el) => {
   $(el).removeClass('anc');
  });
 })
});
```

```css
.anc {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-app">
    <a class="anc">Link1</a>
    <a class="anc">Link2</a>
    <a class="anc">Link3</a>
    <a class="anc">Link4</a>
</div>
<button>Remove class</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the last element of the array of children, using `last`. Thereby it removes the class of only the last child.

try:

```
for(var i=0;i<total;i++)
{
    childElms[i].removeClass('anc');
}
```

Comment: is removing a class equivalent to removing an element. OP has asked to remove an element

Comment: I tried this but accessing using index like this is not working. It still removes class from last element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(var i=0;i<total;i++)
{
    childElms[total-1].removeClass('anc');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly select the last element by using jquery selector and remove the class

```
$('div a:last').removeClass('anc');
```

Answer (score 0):

for your code I understand you want to delete the class `anc` from the last element a. You can do it in this way `document.querySelector('.anc:last-child').classList.remove('anc');` I have added a bit of css to make it easy to appreciate that the class has been removed from the element in question. Please look at the following example

```js
document.querySelector('.anc:last-child').classList.remove('anc');
```

```css
.anc {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-app">
    <a class="anc">Link1</a>
    <a class="anc">Link2</a>
    <a class="anc">Link3</a>
    <a class="anc">Link4</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> On Each iterate you are removing Class of Last Element, without
>   Refreshing your Element Collection.

```js
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    // select elements having class “anc”
    var childElms = $('div').find('.my-app').find('a.anc');
    for(var index=0;index<childElms.length;)
    {
        childElms.last().removeClass('anc');
        childElms = $('div').find('.my-app').find('a.anc'); // refresh element collection
        console.log(`Length: ${childElms.length}`);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="my-app">
        <a class="anc">Link1</a>
        <a class="anc">Link2</a>
        <a class="anc">Link3</a>
        <a class="anc">Link4</a>
      </div>
</div>
```